# WordPress: append query string to all URL's

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A user will be directed from a website to a landing page that will have a query string in the URL i.e. `www.sitename.com?foo=bar&bar=foo`. What I want to do, is then append that query string to all links on the page, *preferably* whether they were generated by WordPress or not (i.e. hard coded or not) and done server-side.

The reason for this is because their goal destination has to have the query string in the URL. I could use cookies, but i'd rather not since it has many other problems that it will bring with it for my specific use case.

I have explored the possibility of using `.htaccess` in conjunction with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to no avail. My understanding of `.htaccess` isn't great, but in my mind I assumed it would be possible to rewrite the current URL to be current URL + the variable that stores `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

I've also explored `add_rewrite_rule` but couldn't find a logical way to achieve what I want.

Here's the Javascript solution I have, but as I said, I'd like a server-side solution:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(link => {

        if (!link.host.includes(location.host)) {
        return;
    }

    const url = new URL(link.href);

    const combined = Array.from(url.searchParams.entries()).reduce((agg, [key, val]) => {
        agg.set(key, val);
        return agg;
}, (new URL(location.href)).searchParams);

    const nextUrl = [link.protocol, '//', link.host, link.pathname].join('');

    link.href = (new URL(`${nextUrl}?${combined.toString()}`)).toString();
});
```

Comment: JavaScript solution is probably more resilient because it doesn't put load on the server & makes the client do the work.

Comment: _“My understanding of .htaccess isn't great, but in my mind I assumed it would be possible to rewrite the current URL to be current URL + the variable that stores $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']”_ - that is not possible, because you _don’t have_ that  query string value available here in the first place. You only have access to the parts of the currently requested URL, but the query string value you are interested in is from the “previous” one. (And “previous” in quotes, because there is no such thing in the _stateless_ realm of HTTP.)

Comment: Doing this client-side via JS probably makes the most sense; alternatively you could use output buffering to catch the whole output, and rewrite the links in there, before you send the whole thing to the browser.